# Is every projective R-module torsion-free? when R is a noncommutative ring!

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, projective-module

Let R be a noncommutative ring, is every projective R-module torsion-free? or, for what kinds of rings (or algebras) the answer is affirmative?

Comment: What do you mean by tosion-free? Is $R$ at least a domain?

Comment: Since projective modules are flat, the solution at the attached question would answer your question.

Comment: thanks Rafi, I think R should be a domain, then Z(M) will be a  submodule!